# Configuring 3-legged OAuth 1.0 in Spring Boot via Java Config (not xml)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, oauth-1.0a

Trying to configure both 3-legged and 2-legged authentication with OAuth 1.0(a) and Spring Boot via Java Configuration (not using XML).

Does anyone have any examples/tutorials for a Java-based configuration for either the 2 or 3 legged approaches?

Thank you,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enroth's answer here worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143001/11274383

Note: We are using OAuth 1.0(a) so on the BaseProtectedResourceDetails I added this to be safe:
details.setUse10a(true);